# What's the best way to provide Profile Edit and Create forms in latest WordPress and CiviCRM?

Tags: wordpress, profile, caldera-forms

So we are currently using the standard shortcodes to embed Profiles in "Edit" mode within WordPress pages to allow members to update their personal details. We also have multi-value custom data groups which we expose in this way.

There is a forked version of the Caldera Forms plugin here: https://lab.civicrm.org/extensions/caldera-civicrm/caldera-forms

There is also an ACF integration plugin here: https://github.com/christianwach/civicrm-acf-integration

And FormBuilder is also an option, along with the FormProcessor extension: https://civicrm.org/form-builder

Which is currently the recommended option, especially when dealing with multi-value custom data groups?

Looking for the most robust, future proof and secure option.

Answer (score 1):

I would rate the combination of FormBuilder and FormProcessor as the most robust, future-proof and secure variant. However, in my opinion there are still quite a few functions missing (see, for example, the ["wish list" of CiviSprint participants Leipzig 2023](https://civicrm.org/blog/detlev/after-camp-sprint) or the [Form Builder roadmap](https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/-/issues/3761)), which is why at the moment it is certainly a matter of weighing up depending on the exact use case. Each of the integrations mentioned has its strengths and weaknesses. Personally, I wouldn't want to miss some of the functions of Caldera Forms + Form Processor and am glad that the Communty fork and the [Caldera Forms Collaboration initiative](https://civicrm.org/blog/jaapjansma/civicoops-caldera-forms-collaboration-initiative) exists until a more complete replacement is available. By the way, this is not meant to sound pessimistic: There is so much happening around SearchKit and FormBuilder every release - many thanks to @Coleman and all who are involved here!

Answer (score 0):

We have been developing and deploying Gravity Forms and CiviCRM integration, which uses Form Processor / Action Provider on the backend. https://github.com/agileware/gf-civicrm

Works great but you need to know what you're doing. RTFM!